# create different styled image attachments with paperclip based on polymorphic model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, attachment

I'm using a polymorphic Picture model to associate images with other models like User, Place etc.

As paperclip docs, Picture model can define a set of styles using:

> has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

But being a polymorphic and associated to different models the required styles per entry will be different. To solve this how can i set custom styles on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use something like what you're referring to.

--

We set the [`Paperclip` defaults](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults) in the `config/application.rb` file:

```
#config/application.rb
...

config.paperclip_defaults = {
   styles: { :large => "x850", :medium => "x450", :thumb => "x200"},
   default_url: "layout/placeholders/:style/placeholder.png"
}
```

This sets a *default* set of styles which can be overridden in the model itself.

We then use an `asset` model (with corresponding DB) to save all the data. This `asset` model then delegates the `url` method (for Paperclip) to its dependent model.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The original code for the polymorphic association is [here](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/08/18/use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads/).

--

Because the Paperclip styles are *defaults*, you can override them as you need in any of your dependent models.